# Windows forms: how get the actual width of the item in the list box

Tags: .net, winforms, listbox

To make sure that the text in listbox items is not truncated I want
to adjust its width to the width of the item with longest text.

Is there any way to get a "actual" width of the listbox item
the one which is based on the item's text.

ListBox.GetItemRectangle does not seem to be returning this actual
width.

thank you.

Comment: please complete the title of this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MeasureString method: (copy pasted from msdn)

```
Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics();
int width = (int)g.MeasureString(aString, control.Font).Width;
g.dispose();
```

Add width of the textbox (left and right side) to the value

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx) method.